# How to turn multiple rows of dictionaries from a file into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, binance

I have a script that I use to fire orders from a csv file, to an exchange using a for loop.

```
data = pd.read_csv('orderparameters.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(len(df)):
    order = Client.new_order(...

   ...)
    file = open('orderData.txt', 'a')
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    with file as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print(order)
        file.close()
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

I put the response from the exchange in a txt file like this...
[image]

I want to turn the multiple responses into 1 single dataframe. I would hope it would look something like...
[image]

(I did that manually).
I tried;

```
data = pd.read_csv('orderData.txt', header=None)
dfData = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(dfData)
```

but I got;
[image]

I have also tried

```
data = pd.read_csv('orderData.txt', header=None)
organised = data.apply(pd.Series)
print(organised)
```

but I got the same output.
I can print order['symbol'] within the loop etc.
I'm not certain whether I should be populating this dataframe within the loop, or by capturing and writing the response and processing it afterwards. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: What you are expecting is a screenshot of an excel file and what you get is the screenshot of a json object (that looks like it has the same data as in the excel file).  What exactly are you hoping to get?  Is what you have in the wrong format or does it have the wrong data (or both)?

Comment: Right data, wrong format. It looks to me like I have 3 dictionaries (appended to a text file of the response) which were created from iterating over a loop of the orders I fired at Binance from the 'orderparameters.csv' file. I want to turn those 3 dictionaries into 1 single new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting json strings back, you could read json objects into dictionaries and then create a dataframe from that.  Perhaps try something like this (no longer needs a file)

```
data = pd.read_csv('orderparameters.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
response_data = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    order_json = Client.new_order(...

   ...)
   response_data.append(eval(order_json))

response_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(response_data)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked perfectly!! I have to turn order_json into a string first, but that's fine, as I can change it back when processing later. Ben, you are a legend. Much obliged!

Comment: `eval` turns a string into a dictionary.  If you are just getting a dictionary back you could use that directly and avoid the unnecessary conversions.  I assumed you were getting a string back

Comment: Useful to know about the eval function though. Definitely going to start using that. Awesome 

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('orderparameters.csv')
responses = pd.DataFrame(Client.new_order(...) for _ in range(len(orders)))
```

Comment: Thanks. No, actually the 'orderparameters.csv' is generated by myself to launch the orders to Binance. It is the response from Binance that I am trying to process. It is inside a loop, because here, in my CSV file, I have 3 orders that I send to binance from the first dataframe. I am looking to create a new dataframe fronm the response

Comment: Yes. That is what my code is doing: using your orders, sending each one to the client, getting the responses, and creating a DataFrame form the list of responses, which I assume are json objects.

Comment: Ah, of course. Yes, perfect. I'm not fluent enough with code to have picked up on that. Thank you